# wait() doesn't block, in Linux and pthreads

Tags: c, linux, pthreads

I have a relatively simple pthread program on Linux. For this purpose, I've stripped it to a small piece, posted at the end.

All the man pages for wait(2) say that wait() will block unless WNOHANG is used (which is not even possible to specify for wait()). Looking at truss output, it's just a non-stop repetition of:

```
5460  wait4(-1, 0x7f8ee479fea8, 0, NULL) = -1 ECHILD (No child processes)
```

again, looking at man page of wait4(2), it says that the return results are same as for waitpid(), and waitpid should block unless there is WNOHANG, and truss shows that the call was made with options being 0.

For reference, this is:

- 2.6.32-300.3.1.el6uek.x86_64
- glibc-2.12-1.47.el6_2.9.x86_64
- gcc-4.4.6-3.el6.x86_64
- compiled with: gcc -pthread -lpthread -o ptw -Wall ptw.c

--

```
#include <pthread.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>



static pthread_mutex_t _lock = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;
static pthread_cond_t  _sem = PTHREAD_COND_INITIALIZER;

static void* waiter(void*);

int main(int argc, char ** argv) {

    pthread_t thr;

    if (pthread_create(&thr, 0, waiter, 0)) {
        perror("pthread_create");
        return 1;
    }

    pthread_mutex_lock(&_lock);
    pthread_cond_wait(&_sem, &_lock);

    return 0;

}

void* waiter(void* arg) {

    while (1) {
        int status;
        int p = wait(&status);
        if (p<0) {
            perror("wait");
            // fprintf(stderr, "wait returned without exited child\n");
        }
    }

    return 0;

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`wait()` will also return immediately if there is no child process to wait for, with value `-1` and `errno` set to `ECHILD` (which is what your `strace` is showing you).  What were you expecting it to do in the case where no child processes exist?

Comment: Thank you. I didn't quite understand what the "unwaited-for children" meant in the man page. My expectation was that it will block, until there is an exited child anyway (e.g. another thread might start a child that may then exit).

Comment: Why, it should wait for a timer signal to go off, which will call a handler, which will `fork()` a child, and then wait for that child. :)

Comment: I should rather wait for SIGCHLD, if using signals :)

Answer (score 1):

The `wait()` call works as documented. What you are running into is an error condition described in `ERRORS` section [here](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man2/wait.2.html):

> ```
>    ECHILD (for wait()) The calling process does not have any unwaited-for
>           children.
>
>    ECHILD (for waitpid() or waitid()) The process specified by pid (waitpid()) or
>           idtype and id (waitid()) does not exist or is not a child of the
>           calling process.  (This can happen for one's own child if the action
>           for SIGCHLD is set to SIG_IGN.  See also the Linux Notes section about
>           threads.)
>
>    EINTR  WNOHANG was not set and an unblocked signal or a SIGCHLD was caught;
>           see signal(7).
>
>    EINVAL The options argument was invalid.
> ```

Thus it doesn't block, because it doesn't make sense to block on error.